# Effect of partitioning the realizations of random variables on the total variation distance?

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, inequalities

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two random variables with joint pmf $p(x,y)=p(x)\cdot p(y|x)$ and $X$ has uniform distribution. Also assume that the following relation is satisfied:
\begin{align}
\lVert p(y|x)-p(y)\rVert_1\leq a.
\end{align}
where $\lVert\cdot\rVert_1$ is the total variation distance. Now, suppose that we group uniformly and independently each two realizations of $X$. We define new random variable $X^\prime$ as
$$X^\prime=x^\prime\leftrightarrow X=\{x_1\text{or}~x_2\}.$$
Thus, we have
$$p(y|x^\prime)=\frac{1}{2}p(y|x_1)+\frac{1}{2}p(y|x_2).$$
It is clear that distribution of $p(y|x^\prime)$ is closer to $p(y)$. Indeed, triangle inequality shows the following:
\begin{align}
\lVert p(y|x^\prime)-p(y)\rVert_1&=\lVert \frac{1}{2}p(y|x_1)+\frac{1}{2}p(y|x_2)-p(y)\rVert_1\\
&\leq\frac{1}{2}\lVert p(y|x_1)-p(y)\rVert_1+\frac{1}{2}\lVert p(y|x_2)-p(y)\rVert_1\\
&\leq a
\end{align}
Now, the question is that how much the grouping could decrease the total variation amount? For example, we can show that grouping random variables results in total variation of $\frac{a}{2}$?

To clarify the question, consider the following joint pmf $p(x,y)$:

\begin{equation}
\begin{matrix}
&y_1&y_2&y_3&y_4\\
x_1&.2&.3&.4&.1\\
x_2&.1&.6&.1&.2\\
x_3&.5&.05&.25&.2\\
x_4&.2&.05&.25&.5
\end{matrix}
\end{equation}

For this pmf, we have:
\begin{align}
\lVert p(y,x)-p(y)p(x)\rVert_1=\sum_{x,y}\frac{1}{4}\lvert p(y|x)-p(y)\rvert=0.525.
\end{align}

Now consider $x^\prime_1=\{x_1,x_2\}$ and $x^\prime_2=\{x_3,x_4\}$. Then,
\begin{align}
\lVert p(y,x^\prime)-p(y)p(x^\prime)\rVert_1=\sum_{x,y}\frac{1}{2}\lvert p(y|x^\prime)-p(y)\rvert=0.4.
\end{align}

and considering $x^\prime_1=\{x_1,x_3\}$ and $x^\prime_2=\{x_2,x_4\}$, we have,
\begin{align}
\lVert p(y,x^\prime)-p(y)p(x^\prime)\rVert_1=\sum_{x,y}\frac{1}{2}\lvert p(y|x^\prime)-p(y)\rvert=0.35.
\end{align}

So, the choice of group members affects the amount of total variation. Now the question is to analyze this effect.

Comment: It depends on how you choose $x_1,x_2$, basically you are mixing two distributions, which does not necessarily lead to reduction of total variance.

Comment: Yes. But there exists such a mixing. I want to know how much the total variation could decrease when we choose $x_1$ and $x_2$ in the best way.

Comment: Can you complement your OP with an example where such a micing strictly reduce total variation and in what sense you mean "best"?